# Why is this creating an infinite loop?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am trying to do a java program using methods in order to construct an hourglass figure that is a specific size based off of a user entry between 3 - 10. When i run the program however, I get an infinite loop.

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

   int height;

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter an integer between 3 and 10 to control the" +
                       " heigth of the hour glass: ");
   height = keyboard.nextInt();                    


    line();
    topHalf();
    bottomHalf();
    line();

 }

public static void line() {

  System.out.println("+");
  for (int i = 1; 1<= 10; i++){
     System.out.println("-");

     System.out.println("+");    
       }   
    }


    public static void topHalf()
     {
          for(int line = 1; line <= 3; line++){
          System.out.println("|");
          for (int i = 1; i<= (line - 1); i++){
             System.out.println(" ");
          }
          System.out.println("\\");
          for (int i = 1; i <= (6 - 2 * line); i++){  
             System.out.println(".");
          }
          System.out.print("/");
          for (int i = 1; i <= (line - 1); i++){
             System.out.println(" ");
          }
          System.out.println("|");    
        }
    }

    public static void bottomHalf()
    {
       for (int line = 1; line <= 3; line++){
          System.out.println("|");
          for (int i = 1; i <= (3 - line); i++){
             System.out.println(" ");
          }
          System.out.println("/");
          for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * (line - 1); i++){
             System.out.println(".");
          }
          System.out.println("\\");
          for (int i = 1; i <= (3 - line); i++){
             System.out.print(" ");
          }
        }
    }

 }
```

I really have no idea what is going on, but i know for certain it is not an hourglass shape. The only thing that is happening when I run it is an infinite loop of + and then -. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have a `1` instead of an `i` in your condition for your `for` loop - `1 <= 10` is always true, hence the infinite loop. You want to change:

```
for (int i = 1; 1<= 10; i++){
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i<= 10; i++){
```

Comment: Any idea on why it is only printing out one symbol for line of code opposed to creating a picture?

Comment: @Drewmeister96 System.out.println prints a line.